# Converting Road Lines to a Binary Raster Image

Tags: qgis, raster, buffer, dissolve, usgs

I got road data from the USGS database and imported it into QGIS.

[image]

And I want to transform it into a binary raster image that looks like this in QGIS (this is only a processed screen shot but I want to be able to control the raster resolution in QGIS)

[image]

So far I've done a buffer and dissolve (Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Buffer(s)...) but I have been unsuccessful in transforming it into a actual raster in QGIS.

Comment: Update: I have tried rasterizing but whenever I do rasterize the roads (even when buffered) I do not get a meaningful road raster image at all, just a solid black rectangle. I used a buffer distance of 0.000025.

Comment: Update 2: I think I figured it out. When I go up to a buffer distance of 0.00005 it works. So maybe there is some minimum buffer distance needed?

Comment: Update 3: Confirmed. Minimum line buffer distance that can be converted into a raster in QGIS 12.2.1 is 0.000042.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Raster|Rasterize|Conversion (Vector to Raster)` menu.

[image]

Choose an appropriate resolution for the raster you need:

[image]

[image]